# Resolving problems with DSL SetUp project

Tags: wix, dsl, vsx

I'm fighting with the InstallerDefinition.dslsetup file in a DSL setup project. I'm getting the following error:

*Running transformation: The setup project could not retrieve the output path for project 'PsiTraffic.Modeling.PomModel.Dsl' from the environment. Ensure that this project exists in the solution. Only Visual C# and Visual Basic project types are supported.*

The Project 'PsiTraffic.Modeling.PomModel.Dsl' is in the solution, its also a project reference of the setup solution. The project is C# so the only two pointer's it gave me are useless.

This is the section that it is reffering to in the dslsetup file:

```
<dslSchemas>
    <dslSchema project="PsiTraffic.Modeling.PomModel.Dsl" filePath="GeneratedCode\PomModelSchema.xsd"/>
</dslSchemas>
```

If I provide a full path to the file the error goes away but this goes against the whole point of the project attribute, and I get errors later from the supportingAssembly attributes.

There aren't very many good examples on this and its Visual Studio doesn't provide you with much in the way of support to diagnose the problem.

Any insights or good examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the problem was down to using solution folders and not having all the projects on the same directory level. This is a truly hideous "feature" as far as I'm concerned, and its really bad that as far as I can see its not documented.

So if you encounter similar problems make sure you're not using subfolders or solution folders.

Comment: You should probably complain about this to someone who can do something about it. Try http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio, or at least the VSX Forum (http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsx/threads/).